# What would cause all my gfi recepticles to not reset in my kitchen?

Tags: electrical

All my recepticles that are gfi except one will not reset nor will the outlets that are protected by them work? My house was built in 2006 and the receptacles are levitons. It tripped the breaker about a week ago then all of them stopped working except one. The one gfi has a crack in it. What do I need to check?

Comment: Which "one" is cracked; the one that works? Are these load fed together or are they individual GFIs? Have you tried unplugging everything that is served by them to see if it will hold?

Comment: Have you reset the breaker?   Most GFIs will not reset with the power off.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the GFI isn't defective, there are three common things that can keep it from resetting:

1. There is no power to the outlet.
2. The GFI is wired in backwards: the wires coming from the breaker box are connected to the "load" side of the outlet rather than the "line" side.
3. There is a ground fault somewhere in the circuit the GFI is protecting.

Given that the breaker tripped, (3) is very much a possibility.  Alternatively, since you say there's a crack, the GFI may have been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I reset breaker and tried to reset and still didn't work. I don't understand why all but one quit working. Is it possible that they are all connected together?